# How to register RouterFunction in @Bean method in Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm playing around with Spring 5 features and I'm having some trouble registering `RouterFunction`, it will be read, but not mapped. (Tried by throwing exception in the method.)

```
@Configuration
@RequestMapping("/routes")
public class Routes {
  @Bean
  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routingFunction() {
    return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.path("/asd"), req -> ok().build());
  }
}
```

Going to `/routes/asd` results in 404, any clues on what I'm doing wrong? 
(I also tried without this `@RequestMapping` to `/routes`, it also returned 404 for `/asd`)

Comment: The `RequestMapping` shouldn't impact the `RouterFunction` mappings. Are sure of the fact that your `Configuration` class is getting picked by the Spring component scanner? Please post more information on your project structure and possible `build.gradle`/`pom.xml`. Except for `RequestMapping`, your `RouterFunction` seems to be fine

Comment: I have a simple main class annotated with '@SpringBootApplication', which calls SpringApplication.run(TestfluxApplication.class, args);

The other class is the 'Routes' class posted above. 

The pom.xml is using spring-boot-starter-parent as a parent; it has spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux as dependencies. If I add new class with '@RestController', it gets picked up, and mappings in it are applied and accessible.

Comment: I threw exception in this routing method, which is not applied, and the stacktrace looks like this:

https://pastebin.com/raw/44Bh7yv2
(So I guess it's picked up)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the issue.

I had those dependencies both in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

removed the spring-boot-starter-web dependency and webflux started working properly.

Another solution was to keep the web dependency and exclude tomcat so netty started working:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

No need add `spring-boot-starter-web` when you want to use Webflux, just add `spring-boot-starter-webflux` into project dependencies.

For your codes, remove `@RequestMapping("/routes")` if want to use pure `RouterFunction`. And your `routingFunction` bean does not specify which HTTP method will be used.

A working sample codes from my github:

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(PostHandler postController) {
    return route(GET("/posts"), postController::all)
        .andRoute(POST("/posts"), postController::create)
        .andRoute(GET("/posts/{id}"), postController::get)
        .andRoute(PUT("/posts/{id}"), postController::update)
        .andRoute(DELETE("/posts/{id}"), postController::delete);
}
```

Check the complete codes from: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/boot-routes

If you are stick on traditional `@RestController` and `@RequestMapping`, check another sample: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/boot